# Is there any way to show combined search result from an external api and also internal content from drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 website which shows articles from an external API. also my basic page contents are coming from Drupal itself. I need to implement a search functionality so that search will return combined results from Drupal internal contents like basic pages and also from the external API too.

Comment: You have to research for BigQuery and implement distance. Also API should have some sort of relevance info (compare mark), to be able to combine both results

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both the result like this :

1. Call external API and store result in in one array.
2. Get basic page content using database query and store it in one array.
3. Combine both array and display it.

Comment: This is basic approach, how you going to deal with relevance?